# Car stalls when trying to accelerate after a stop

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission, stall, chrysler, town-and-country

I have a 2015 Chrysler Town and Country with ~70k miles; check engine light is off.

Recently, over the past 2-3 months it has developed a symptom where the car randomly stalls when accelerating after a stop. I've counted 4 occurrences so far.

Examples:

- Driving, full stop at red light, press gas, car stalls
- Car parked, turn it on, put in reverse, press gas, car stalls
- Align self to parking spot, put car in reverse, press gas, car stalls

The remedy is to apply the brake, place in park, and start the car. The symptom has not happened consecutively nor is it predictable.

When it stalls, it seems like the transmission puts itself in neutral because the car will roll if brake is not applied. When it stalls, there is no sharp jerk, the engine just kind of shuts off as if I put it in park and turned the car off myself.

---

Possibly relevant, for about 5 months now the car will randomly get stuck in a low gear like 1-3 (limp mode) and refuse to shift higher unless I park the car, shut if off, and turn it back on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

The transmission fluid was low.

---

I did some digging and decided that maybe the transmission clutch solenoid and/or solenoid pack had gone bad so I replaced those. However, the issue persisted.

I bought a good code reader and saw that `P083B` was being thrown. I bought a dipstick for my van, followed the procedures, and it turned out I was about a quart low on transmission oil.

The worst part is that I had a shop change my fluid after the limp mode issue but before the stalling issue. I can only assume they put in as much fluid as they drained but failed to use a dipstick so the low fluid went undetected.